# ItextPdf : get Y position

Tags: itext, itextpdf

I'm using itextpdf 5 in my project

I want to draw a change bar for any element.

My method drawBar take in input Y1 and Y2 positions like this :

```
drawBar(float y1, float y2, PdfWriter writer){
// draw bar
}
```

But I dont know how to get Y position for current pointer. Is it feasible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the [`getVerticalPosition()`](http://developers.itextpdf.com/reference/com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter#l4mpu9dnnj8) method on the `PdfWriter`. To get the "current" `Y` pass `false` to this and to get the "next" `Y` as if a line break were added pass `true`.